# identifier 'sort' is undefined c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

vector<int> randVect(int amount, int min, int max);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

vector<int> values = randVect(10, 1, 50);

sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](int x, int y){return x < y;});
for (auto val: values){
    cout << val << endl;
}

return 0;
};


vector<int> randVect(int amount, int min, int max){
    vector<int> vecVals;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = 0, randVal = 0;
    while(i < amount){
        randVal = min + rand() % ((max + 1) - min);
        vecVals.push_back(randVal);
        i++;
    }
    return vecVals;
}
```

// I am trying to sort random values that is located in a vector and for that i have to use the sort() function but it is telling me that identifier 'sort' undefined... how can i fix this?

Comment: [`#include <algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#mw-content-text) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should include header `#include <algorithm>` sort algorithm defined there.